# Python How to retrieve a specific cell value from a csv file based on other cell values in the same row without using pandas?

Tags: python, csv

Currently, I have a code whereby "users" will key in their username and password to log in.

```
uname = input("Enter uname: ")
pword = input("Enter pword: ")
.
.
.
if row[1] == pword and row[0] == uname:
    LOGIN()
```

However, I wish to add an "update info" and "generate report" function.

How can I code, using python, such that I can retrieve the "e unit price" of a specific row of the CSV file? (e.g. uname = donnavan12 and pword = Onwdsna)?

[image]

Another question that I have is: How can I code, using python, such that I can retrieve the sum of a particular column (e.g. "energy saved") with (e.g. uname = donnavan12 and pword = Onwdsna)?

[image]

Sorry that I don't have codes of what I have tried because I don't even know where to begin. I only learned basic python in the past and used dataframe which was much easier but in this project, Pandas is not allowed so I'm rather stumped. (I also added minimal code as I'm afraid of getting my groupmates striked for plagiarism. Please let me know if more code is necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DictReader` in the `csv` module

**Example code:**

```py
mcsv = csv.DictReader(filename)

rows = list(mcsv)


def get_value(myname, mypass, clm):
    for row in rows:
        if row['uname']==myname and row['pass'] == mypass:
            return row['e unit price']


def set_value(myname, mypass, clm, new_value):
    for row in rows:
        if row['uname']==myname and row['pass'] == mypass:
            row[clm] = new_value


def get_sum(myname, mypass, clm):
    esaved = 0
    for row in rows:
        if row['uname']==myname and row['pass'] == mypass:
            esaved += int(row[clm])
    return esaved


print('energy saved: ', get_sum(myname, mypass, 'energy saved'))
print('e unit price before: ', get_value(myname, mypass, 'e unit price'))

set_value(myname, mypass, 'e unit price', 201)
print('e unit price after: ', get_value(myname, mypass, 'e unit price'))
```

**Input**

| uname | pass | e unit price | energy saved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 100 | 10 |
| cde | 456 | 101 | 11 |
| abc | 123 | 100 | 13 |
| fgh | 789 | 102 | 12 |

**Output**

```
energy saved:  23
e unit price before:  100
e unit price after:  201
```

Comment: May I ask what I can do if I want to update the values in the csv file? For example, if I want to change the "e unit price" of uname: abc from 102 to 201

Comment: @clueless Sure I've added a function to set new value to a cell. Try it.